# Laravel Routing (9.x) Unable to route to custom function

Tags: php, laravel

Need help with Laravel Routing. It has not been my forte on this personal project, and I have not had a chance to code in the past 3 months...

I'm writing code for a property maintenance site, where users track their properties and tenancies. I want to provide the user with the convenience of extending a tenancy, with some automated updates such as update the startDate, and endDate by a year, and giving it a new unique reference. The user will be shown the new page and they can amend further and save.

The below function is in my TenanciesController.php

```
public function extend(Tenancies $tenancy)
    {           
        $newModel = $tenancy->replicate();
        $newModel->created_at = now(); // not sure if necessary, or if it'll be changed once the model is stored in the database
                
        $startDate = new DateTime($tenancy->end_date);
        $newModel->start_date = $startDate->modify("+ 1 minute");
        $endDate = new DateTime($tenancy->end_date);
        $newModel->end_date = $startDate->modify("+ 1 year");
        
        $newModel->reference = $this->getUniqueReference();

        $request->session()->put('_old_input', $newModel);
        //return redirect(route('models.create'));
        echoToConsole('Replica:',$newModel);
        echoToConsole('Original:',$tenancy);
        
        return view('tenancies.create', [
                'property' => $newModel->property(),
        ]);        
    }
```

my issue is in routing in web.php, as I cannot get routed to the extend function.

In my view (show.blade.php) I have the following button:

```
<x-primary-button>
    <a href="{{ route('tenancies.extend', [$tenancy->reference])}}" >{{ __('Extend') }}</a>
</x-primary-button>
```

in web.php, this is my routing which results in Error 404 whether I pass the refernce in the parameter (http://localhost/tenancies/1BQSD8923/extend) or the id (http://localhost/tenancies/8/extend):

```
use App\Models\Tenancies;

Route::get('/tenancies/{tenancy}/extend', function (Tenancies $tenancy) {
    return $tenancy->reference;
});

Route::get('/tenancies/{tenancy}/extend', [TenanciesController::class, 'extend'])->name('tenancies.extend');


Route::resource('tenancies', TenanciesController::class)
->only(['index', 'create','store', 'edit','update','show','destroy'])
->middleware(['auth', 'verified']);
```

I've also tried the following in web.php:

```
Route::get('tenancies/{tenancies:$reference}/extend', [TenanciesController::class, 'hide'])->name('tenancies.extend');

  Route::resource('tenancies', TenanciesController::class)
    ->only(['index', 'create','store', 'edit','update','show','destroy'])
    ->middleware(['auth', 'verified']);
```

the tenancies model is using reference column as getrouteKey

```
public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return 'reference';
    }
```

Please help, I'm not sure what I'm getting wrong.

Comment: You have defined the same route twice. And neither definition is protected by auth middleware. Have you confirmed that your route shows up as expected in `artisan route:list`?

Comment: Route model binding is very strict. `/tenancies/{tenancy}/extend` is your route, but in your blade your param is `[$tenancy->reference]` ? What is it? A reference or a tenancy? First solve your 404 error by (look at this comment above me) solving the 2 get routes. Make it simple first, then ... extend with route model binding

Comment: Thanks I've remove 1 of the routes, and kept - Route::get('/tenancies/{tenancy}/extend', [TenanciesController::class, 'extend'])->name('tenancies.extend')->middleware(['auth', 'verified']);
In the blade: <a href="{{ route('tenancies.extend', [$tenancy])}}" >{{ __('Extend') }}</a> The route does show up in artisan route:list: GET|HEAD        tenancies/{tenancy}/extend tenancies.extend › TenanciesControl…
I'm still getting a 404.

Comment: Progress: Route::get('/tenancies/{tenancy}/extend',  function (Tenancies $tenancy) {
    echo 'tenancy: '.$tenancy;
    
    //return $tenancy;
})->name('tenancies.extend')->middleware(['auth', 'verified']); shows me a JSON with the tenancy details. How do I now call the controller extend method?

Comment: OK, it all clicked now! The route didn't need to be complex at all. The Error 404 wasn't coming from routing but coming from the controller, but I couldn't see that. There were a lot of errors, and thanks to comments from miken32 and UnderDog, I cleared my thinking. Solution: Route: Route::get('/tenancies/{tenancy}/extend', [TenanciesController::class, 'extend'])->name('tenancies.extend')->middleware(['auth', 'verified']); Blade:<a href="{{ route('tenancies.extend', ['tenancy'=>$tenancy])}}" >{{ __('Extend') }}</a>

Answer (score 0):

Update blade to pass tenancy (not a reference):

```
<x-primary-button>
   <a href="{{ route('tenancies.extend', ['tenancy'=>$tenancy])}}" >{{ __('Extend') }}</a>
</x-primary-button>
```

Keep 1 route:

```
Route::get('/tenancies/{tenancy}/extend', [TenanciesController::class, 'extend'])->name('tenancies.extend')->middleware(['auth', 'verified']);
```